# JS issue in top menu block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, prestashop

I have a problem with my top menu, when the categories have no childrens, they are not getting any class, so the style is not applied correctly.

Any ideas how to solve that?

the js file that applies the classes to the category is :

```
/* * jQuery Superfish Menu Plugin - v1.7.4
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Joel Birch
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */
(function($) {
    "use strict";


    var methods = (function() {
        // private properties and methods go here
        var c = {
                bcClass: 'sf-breadcrumb',
                menuClass: 'sf-js-enabled',
                anchorClass: 'sf-with-ul',
                menuArrowClass: 'sf-arrows'
            },
            ios = (function() {
                var ios = /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
                if (ios) {
                    // iOS clicks only bubble as far as body children
                    $(window).load(function() {
                        $('body').children().on('click', $.noop);
                    });
                }
                return ios;
            })(),
            wp7 = (function() {
                var style = document.documentElement.style;
                return ('behavior' in style && 'fill' in style && /iemobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
            })(),
            toggleMenuClasses = function($menu, o) {
                var classes = c.menuClass;
                if (o.cssArrows) {
                    classes += ' ' + c.menuArrowClass;
                }
                $menu.toggleClass(classes);
            },
            setPathToCurrent = function($menu, o) {
                return $menu.find('li.' + o.pathClass).slice(0, o.pathLevels)
                    .addClass(o.hoverClass + ' ' + c.bcClass)
                    .filter(function() {
                        return ($(this).children(o.popUpSelector).hide().show().length);
                    }).removeClass(o.pathClass);
            },
            toggleAnchorClass = function($li) {
                $li.children('a').toggleClass(c.anchorClass);
            },
            toggleTouchAction = function($menu) {
                var touchAction = $menu.css('ms-touch-action');
                touchAction = (touchAction === 'pan-y') ? 'auto' : 'pan-y';
                $menu.css('ms-touch-action', touchAction);
            },
            applyHandlers = function($menu, o) {
                var targets = 'li:has(' + o.popUpSelector + ')';
                if ($.fn.hoverIntent && !o.disableHI) {
                    $menu.hoverIntent(over, out, targets);
                } else {
                    $menu
                        .on('mouseenter.superfish', targets, over)
                        .on('mouseleave.superfish', targets, out);
                }
                var touchevent = 'MSPointerDown.superfish';
                if (!ios) {
                    touchevent += ' touchend.superfish';
                }
                if (wp7) {
                    touchevent += ' mousedown.superfish';
                }
                $menu
                    .on('focusin.superfish', 'li', over)
                    .on('focusout.superfish', 'li', out)
                    .on(touchevent, 'a', o, touchHandler);
            },
            touchHandler = function(e) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    $ul = $this.siblings(e.data.popUpSelector);


                if ($ul.length > 0 && $ul.is(':hidden')) {
                    $this.one('click.superfish', false);
                    if (e.type === 'MSPointerDown') {
                        $this.trigger('focus');
                    } else {
                        $.proxy(over, $this.parent('li'))();
                    }
                }
            },
            over = function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    o = getOptions($this);
                clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);
                $this.siblings().superfish('hide').end().superfish('show');
            },
            out = function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    o = getOptions($this);
                if (ios) {
                    $.proxy(close, $this, o)();
                } else {
                    clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);
                    o.sfTimer = setTimeout($.proxy(close, $this, o), o.delay);
                }
            },
            close = function(o) {
                o.retainPath = ($.inArray(this[0], o.$path) > -1);
                this.superfish('hide');


                if (!this.parents('.' + o.hoverClass).length) {
                    o.onIdle.call(getMenu(this));
                    if (o.$path.length) {
                        $.proxy(over, o.$path)();
                    }
                }
            },
            getMenu = function($el) {
                return $el.closest('.' + c.menuClass);
            },
            getOptions = function($el) {
                return getMenu($el).data('sf-options');
            };


        return {
            // public methods
            hide: function(instant) {
                if (this.length) {
                    var $this = this,
                        o = getOptions($this);
                    if (!o) {
                        return this;
                    }
                    var not = (o.retainPath === true) ? o.$path : '',
                        $ul = $this.find('li.' + o.hoverClass).add(this).not(not).removeClass(o.hoverClass).children(o.popUpSelector),
                        speed = o.speedOut;


                    if (instant) {
                        $ul.show();
                        speed = 0;
                    }
                    o.retainPath = false;
                    o.onBeforeHide.call($ul);
                    $ul.stop(true, true).animate(o.animationOut, speed, function() {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        o.onHide.call($this);
                    });
                }
                return this;
            },
            show: function() {
                var o = getOptions(this);
                if (!o) {
                    return this;
                }
                var $this = this.addClass(o.hoverClass),
                    $ul = $this.children(o.popUpSelector);


                o.onBeforeShow.call($ul);
                $ul.stop(true, true).animate(o.animation, o.speed, function() {
                    o.onShow.call($ul);
                });
                return this;
            },
            destroy: function() {
                return this.each(function() {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        o = $this.data('sf-options'),
                        $hasPopUp;
                    if (!o) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    $hasPopUp = $this.find(o.popUpSelector).parent('li');
                    clearTimeout(o.sfTimer);
                    toggleMenuClasses($this, o);
                    toggleAnchorClass($hasPopUp);
                    toggleTouchAction($this);
                    // remove event handlers
                    $this.off('.superfish').off('.hoverIntent');
                    // clear animation's inline display style
                    $hasPopUp.children(o.popUpSelector).attr('style', function(i, style) {
                        return style.replace(/display[^;]+;?/g, '');
                    });
                    // reset 'current' path classes
                    o.$path.removeClass(o.hoverClass + ' ' + c.bcClass).addClass(o.pathClass);
                    $this.find('.' + o.hoverClass).removeClass(o.hoverClass);
                    o.onDestroy.call($this);
                    $this.removeData('sf-options');
                });
            },
            init: function(op) {
                return this.each(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if ($this.data('sf-options')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.superfish.defaults, op),
                        $hasPopUp = $this.find(o.popUpSelector).parent('li');
                    o.$path = setPathToCurrent($this, o);


                    $this.data('sf-options', o);


                    toggleMenuClasses($this, o);
                    toggleAnchorClass($hasPopUp);
                    toggleTouchAction($this);
                    applyHandlers($this, o);


                    $hasPopUp.not('.' + c.bcClass).superfish('hide', true);


                    o.onInit.call(this);
                });
            }
        };
    })();


    $.fn.superfish = function(method, args) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            return $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.fn.superfish');
        }
    };


    $.fn.superfish.defaults = {
        popUpSelector: 'ul,.sf-mega', // within menu context
        hoverClass: 'sfHover',
        pathClass: 'overrideThisToUse',
        pathLevels: 1,
        delay: 800,
        animation: {
            opacity: 'show'
        },
        animationOut: {
            opacity: 'hide'
        },
        speed: 'normal',
        speedOut: 'fast',
        cssArrows: true,
        disableHI: false,
        onInit: $.noop,
        onBeforeShow: $.noop,
        onShow: $.noop,
        onBeforeHide: $.noop,
        onHide: $.noop,
        onIdle: $.noop,
        onDestroy: $.noop
    };


    // soon to be deprecated
    $.fn.extend({
        hideSuperfishUl: methods.hide,
        showSuperfishUl: methods.show
    });


})(jQuery);
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see where is the code where you supply the categories. How do you add them?

Comment: I really do not know... where should it be? Do you know prestashop? I did not modify nothing on prestashop side, just the css....

Comment: you have a link to the shop?

Comment: in the default prestashop theme there shouldn't be any classes in your li css. the only class it's the "sf-with-ul" added to an item when it has some submenu, but that's should be only used to display the relative subitem and not to style the whole element.

Comment: so...what's the solution? What should I have to do?